# How to convert Map<Object, Object> to Map<String, String> in java?

Tags: java, dictionary, inputstream

I have the Map of type Object, i need to convert this map into the type String.

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
Properties properties = new Properties();    
properties.load(instream);
```

Can any body please tell me, how to assign the properties to above map?

Thanks & Regards,
Msnaidu

Comment: What kind of object is `Properties`?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3958306/1862502

Comment: @TimothyGroote - I think it's very likely ot be a `java.util.Properties`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting java.util.Properties To HashMap<string,string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17209260/converting-java-util-properties-to-hashmapstring-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cleanest way to add the properties to the map would be (following on from your example):

```
for (String propName : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
    map.put(propName, properties.getProperty(propName));
}
```

This works nicely in this particular case, because the `Properties` object is really a map containing String keys and values, as the `getProperty` method makes clear.  It's only declared as `Map<Object, Object>` for horrible backwards-compatibility reasons.

By using the Properties-specific methods, rather than treating this as just a `Map<Object, Object>`, you can populate your `Map<String, String>` with perfect type-safety (rather than having to cast).

Comment: I was curious about the reasons for Properties extending HashMap<Object, Object> and found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873510/why-does-java-util-properties-implement-mapobject-object-and-not-mapstring-st

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String, String> properties2Map(Properties p) {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            for(Map.Entry<Object, Object> entry : p.entrySet()) {
                String key = (String) entry.getKey(); //not really unsafe, since you just loaded the properties
                map.put(key, p.getProperty(key));
            }
            return map;
}
```

I also like to use utility methods with type arguments to walk around generic type invariance and do some "downcasting" or "upcasting" (when I KNOW it is safe to do so). In this case:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
<A, B extends A> Map<B, B> downCastMap(Map<A,A> map) {
    return (Map<B, B>)map;
}
```

Then you can write

```
Properties p = ...
Map<String, String> map = downCastMap(p);
```

Comment: can i put it like Map<String, String> map = (Map) properties;

Comment: Yes, suppressing rawtypes and unchecked.  However, the utility method is more code documenting for anyone else (and yourself) reading the code.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly convert:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>((Map)properties);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because we *know* that the Properties are a String-to-String mapping already, it's save to do it with rawtype and unchecked conversion. Just leave a comment:

```
    Properties properties = new Properties();    
    properties.load(instream); 

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    // this is save because Properties have a String to String mapping
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap(properties);
```

Comment: Yes, but why create a new HashMap instance in the process?

Comment: Because we can't *change* or *cast* an instance of Properties to the type `Map<String, String>` because it implements the interface `Map<Object, Object>`.

Comment: Have a look at my answer above and the comments.

Answer (score 1):

With [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/java8-2100321.html) and the addition of [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), I would suggest you to use the APIs Steam provides

Here, we assuming that each of the values actually are String objects, the cast to String should be safe:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<String,String> stringifiedMapSafe = map.entrySet().stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (String)e.getValue()));
```

Now, in case we not sure that all the element are `String`, and we want to filter the key/values with `null`:

```
Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<>();

Map<String,String> stringifiedMapNotSafe = map.entrySet().stream()
             .filter(m -> m.getKey() != null && m.getValue() !=null)
             .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> (String)e.getValue()));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String,String> getPropInMap(Properties prop){       
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (Object key : prop .keySet()) {
        myMap.put(key.toString(), prop .get(key).toString());
    }       
    return myMap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over Map Object, take k v, make them string and put it to a Map String.

```
Map<Object,Object> map1; // with object k,v
Map<String, String> mapString = new HashMap<String, String>();
for (Object key : map1.keySet()) {
                String k = key.toString();
                String v = mmap1.get(key).toString();
                mapString.put(k, v);
            }
```