# Convert Java Map Enum keys to Map String keys

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8

I have the following map:

```
Map<DataFields, String> myMap;
```

But I need to convert it to the following:

```
Map<String, String> myMap;
```

My best feeble attempt which doesn't even compile is:

```
myMap.keySet().stream().map(k -> k.name()).collect(Collectors.toMap(k, v)
```

Comment: I think you might need to use `entrySet()` instead of `keySet()`.

Comment: not sure if FP reduces any efficiency. Another answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208346/how-to-convert-mapobject-object-to-mapstring-string-in-java

Comment: Also, not sure why you needed such a map. Wherever you have to use this map you could have effectively converted the key to string and then used.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to stream the `entrySet()` (so you have both the keys and the values), and collect them to a map:

```
Map<String, String> result =
    myMap.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().name(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: `e -> e.getValue()` replace with `Entry::getValue`

Comment: Eugene it's just a syntactic sugar. Any performance advantage of using `Entry::getValue`

Comment: @AdeshKumar first, unless you tag me with `@`, I can't tell you commented, second is that a question or an affirmation?

Comment: Yes, it's advantageous for both performance and readability to use method references where possible.

Comment: @AdeshKumar a lambda expression will create one more synthetic method, while method references will not, that's about the only difference (besides readability)

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<String, String> result = myMap
    .entrySet() // iterate over all entries (object with tow fields: key and value)
    .stream() // create a stream
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey().toString(), e -> e.getValue()));
        // collect to map: convert enum Key value toString() and copy entry value
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use `name()` over `toString()` which is the reason I'll accept the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing same without Collectors helper. Using `entryset` will make it very easy to map.

```
  map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(
                        () -> new HashMap<String, String>(),
                        (Map newMap, Map.Entry<DataFields, String> entry) -> {
                            newMap.put(entry.getKey().name(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                        ,
                        (Map map1, Map map2) -> {
                            map.putAll(map2);
                        }
                );
```

Answer (score 2):

A Java 8, succint way to do it (without streams):

```
Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<>();
myMap.forEach((k, v) -> result.put(k.name(), v));
```