# Android:how to store and retrieve Hashmap data in sharedpreferences?

Tags: java, android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I want to store some data like key and value pair in internal storage.
so i am using HashMap to store key,value pair .but i don'get sufficient solution to store and retrieve this HashMap into sharedpreferences. 
Please give me some solution.

i am put my code below:

```
HashMap<String, String> MapListMesasges = new HashMap<String, String>();
MapListMesasges.put(FromName, message.getBody());
preferences = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                                SharePreference_messages_history_name,
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        for (Entry<String, String> entry : MapListMesasges
                                .entrySet()) {
                            editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                        }
                        editor.commit();
```

and retrieve data from Sharedprefernces:

```
preferences = mActivity.getSharedPreferences(
                SharePreference_messages_history_name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        for (Entry<String, ?> entry : preferences.getAll().entrySet()) {
            MapListMesasges.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().toString());
        }
```

i will also store hashmap in adapter and  set into listview.
My main purpose is to store and retrieve data into sharedprefernces and also show data into listview.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you print a data in log??that are you getting or not?

Comment: What's the problem? Are you having null when you are retrieving the values?

Comment: `SharedPreferences` are not meant to be used like that. You can however use it like that and the code looks as if it would work. But you shoud consider using a database or something else if you have an undefined set of keys.

Comment: i have to store that data into internal storage.so i am using sharedpreferences.yes i have to retrieve values.but i don't know how to store that hashmap in listview.

Comment: Pass that hasmap list to your custom adpater as parameters..and set to it your listview.

Comment: if you are retrieving your data properly in hash map list then it is easier to store data with listview..

Comment: @dipali....i think you are getting your data in listview properly..isn't it??

Comment: if you have any query then you are get your solution in chat room where many android developers advised you.

Comment: At any where are you clear the data from shared preference before set to listview??

Comment: yes.i have use simple arraylist using getter/setter method and store data into sharedprefernces.

Comment: [saving hashmap to sharedpreferences][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944601/saving-a-hash-map-into-shared-preferences

Comment: Serialize the Map in Json and save it like a simple string. Bad idea but I think it will work

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to store HashMap in Preferences is just convert it to the string and store it.

On the Otherside get that string convert it in HashMap and enjoy.

To Convert String to HashMap & vice-versa check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3957122/801369) link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json for solution.

For example:

```
**JSON**

    {
     [
      "name1","message1",
      "name2","message2"
     ]
    }
```

Store this entire json string with some key and use same key to retrieve. 
Just you need to parse/create JSON. You can use GSON lib for JSON creation/parsing

Answer (score 0):

There's special thing for doing operations like you described and this is [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/package-summary.html).
But if you really want to store them in SharedPreferences, you can do it.
Your solution almost work. You just need to store keys as well.

```
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<String, String> entry : MapListMesasges.entrySet()) {
      editor.putString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
      if(b.length() != 0){
           b.append(",");
      }
      b.append(entry.getKey());
 }
editor.putString("KEY_FOR_PREF_KEYS",b.toString());
```

And to retrieve data use this

```
String[] keys = preferences.getString("KEY_FOR_PREF_KEYS","").split(",");
for (int i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
    MapListMesasges.put(keys[i], preferences.getString(keys[i]));
}
```