# Reading a text file to a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a text file in the following format:

```
Student1 Marks
Student2 Marks
```

The first column is the key.

This is what I have tried so far

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("marks.txt"));

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");

        map.put(columns[0],columns[1]);
    }

    System.out.println(map);        


}
```

Comment: What is your question? How to print the map back?

Comment: it looks like if you split just on " " rather than "\t" it should work

Comment: also, you are putting a `String` value when it should be an `Integer`

Comment: @ControlAltDel: Since the `split` takes a regex, then I think that `\s+` would work better.

Comment: or better yet, split with "\\s"

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920135/printing-hashmap-in-java

Comment: @ControlAltDel, npinti: mixing both your answers, "\\s+"  ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you parse the marks and that the values are indeed tab separated, otherwise code worked for me right away

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileReader("marks.txt"));

    HashMap<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String,Integer>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String[] columns = scanner.nextLine().split("\t");

        map.put(columns[0],Integer.parseInt(columns[1]));
    }

    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: Or juts do `split("\\s+")`, which will split by any number of whitespaces.

Comment: It gives me an error:** The method put(String, Integer) in the type HashMap<String,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String, String)**

Comment: @user3402248 That is the error I got when I ran your code. Just use Integer.parseInt on the second parameter of map.put() and the error will be fixed

Answer (score 0):

(With a little help from the comments) your code should be reading into the `HashMap` already, so i assume your problem is printing the `HashMap` after reading it in.

`System.out.println(map)` only gives you the representation of the map object.
I suggest reading this:
[Convert HashMap.toString() back to HashMap in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957094/convert-hashmap-tostring-back-to-hashmap-in-java)

To print all elements of that HasMap you could iterate over it, like shown here: [Iterate through a HashMap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066589/iterate-through-a-hashmap)